# How can I use gettext before install?

Tags: gettext, autotools

To use gettext, I need to call bindtextdomain(), providing a patch to the installed .mo files. For instance:

```
bindtextdomain("myappname", "/opt/gnome/share/locale");
```

Of course, I use defines there, which are set by my autotools build files.

However, I'd like to use gettext before running "make install", because I want to use the translations in "make check" tests.

The path for bindtextdomain() would normally contain .mo files in a structure like this:

```
de/LC_MESSAGES/myappname.mo
fr/LC_MESSAGES/myappname.mo
```

Is there any easy way to create that structure of generated files in my local build, so I can just pass a local path to bindtextdomain() during "make check"?